# Weird strectching

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

For some unknown reason I seem to be having a problem with my model. This is how it looks like in the game which I'm trying to make it for.

[image: First picture]

[image]

As you can see the quad seems to be inside the thigh somehow. Also the arms are bugged. I had to weight paint this manually to make it work and since I'm basically still a beginner I probably messed up somewhere.

My .blend file can be found here: [image]

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2776" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2776/)

Comment: That *can* be a scale problem on the 'dark apostle' mesh which is not handled correctly at export or in the game engine you are using. Scales are 0.826. So select the mesh, and apply the scale (ctrl+A then scale)

Comment: In which format here you exporting the mesh and armature?

Comment: .smd is the format i believe

Comment: Does that have any thing to do with it? i can't really change the format

Comment: I don't know smd... try to check if there is some interesting options in the bottom left panel when exporting from Blender

Comment: I decompile this way https://gyazo.com/55de2ccc561b0395ac60dd48eec1df2a

Comment: So there is no one who can help me?